# How to use if-else in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
function test(number) {
    if (number % 15 == 0) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    }

    if (number % 3 == 0) {
        return "Fizz";
    }

    if (number % 5 == 0) {
        return "Buzz";
    }

    return number.toString();
}
```

I type `test(15)`.

result print `"FizzBuzz"`

Why doesn't it  print `"FizzBuzz"` `"Fizz"` and `"Buzz"` ?

Comment: because it fulfills one condition and returns -- it doesn't make it to the other conditions.

Comment: because `return` breaks out of the function

Comment: because of the `return` which means: at this point jump out of function and return the specific value

Comment: Probably because the function terminates at the first `return`.

Comment: This is why fizzbuzz exists...

Comment: I dont see any **else** in the code

Comment: @Mils I suspect that was part of the question- if there was no else, why not print (of course that's because of return...)

Answer (score 2):

You can only `return` once per function. After return it goes back to the line were you called the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you `return`, the fuction is terminated and the passed value is returned. Any code that follows the return is not executed.

In your case, the function enters the first statement (as the `number % 15 == 0` statement returns true), sees a return, returns `FizzBuzz`, and breaks out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you leave the function with a return write this instead

```
function test(number) {
        var res = "";
        if(number % 15 == 0){
            res += "FizzBuzz";
        }
        if(number % 3 == 0){
            res += "Fizz";
        }
        if(number % 5 ==0){
            res += "Buzz";
        }
        return res;
}
```

It will add the results from the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

[@Yehuda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43637114/4927984) correctly explained *why* it only display FizzBuzz: The execution of a function is stopped when you return.

Here is one of the (many) solutions to get all the modulos: It defines an array which in you can store the modulos. At the end of the code, it returns the array.

```js
function test(number) {
    var res = [];
    if(number % 15 == 0) {
        res.push("FizzBuzz");
    }
    if(number % 3 == 0) {
        res.push("Fizz");
    }
    if(number % 5 == 0) {
        res.push("Buzz");
    }
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}
test(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return varius:

```
function test(number) {
        res = '';
        if(number % 15 == 0){
            res +=   " FizzBuzz";
        }
        if(number % 3 == 0){
            res +=   " Fizz";
        }
        if(number % 5 ==0){
            res +=  " Buzz";
        }
        return number + " - "  + res.toString();
}
```